# OS X Yosemite spotlight search wikipedia and web content missing

Tags: spotlight, macos

One of the new features in spotlight was supposed to be information from wikipedia, web when anything was searched. However, I don't seem to be getting this information when I search in spotlight. Is this feature only available in certain countries? (Im in India, and all the reviews I've read about Yosemite are US or Europe based websites).

Comment: There are reports from random sources that this service is not available outside of the US; however, there's no official word from Apple confirming this. I have the same problem and am curious to see if anyone has a solution here.

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm in Slovenia, setting the `Preferred language` to English and `Region` to United States does not help.

Answer (score 6):

This could be related: https://www.apple.com/ios/feature-availability/#spotlight-suggestions-spotlight-suggestions

It's a list of countries that have Spotlight Suggestions enabled in iOS 8. If this is true, this is a pretty bad move from Apple.

Source: [macrumors discussion](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=20161720&postcount=12)

**UPDATE**: Apple confirms that

> Spotlight Suggestions may not be available in all regions.

on the [Spotlight support page](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH18828).

Answer (score 1):

Appart from @shrx correct answer there is a second issue with Yosemite's new Spotlight feature:

On my system I was able to enable Wikipedia and Web content by aligning my system's region and language settings.

Source: http://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/2joxlh/os_x_yosemite_1010_bug_thread/cldpzkh

Comment: Can confirm this worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

This feature is not available in India.